# Knockout : populate observable property on a drop-down selection

Tags: knockout.js

Hi could you please help me with following:

I have model:

```
// Form model
function Form(form, title, max) {
  this.Form = ko.observable(form);
  this.Title = ko.observable(title);
  this.Max = ko.observable(max);
}
```

Where is 'Form' property is populating on a View from this array:

```
var forms = ['T-01', 'T-02', 'T-03'];
```

Like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: forms,
        value: Form,
        optionsCaption: 'Select...'">
</select>
```

Question: How can I populate 'Title' property based on selected Form also I need my output JSON should looking like this:

```
"Forms": [
  {
   "Form": "T-01",
   "Title": "",
   "MAX": 0
  }
  ...
```

Because when I try to store my data like this:

```
var forms = [
  { name: 'T-01', title: 'Test 1' },
  { name: 'T-02', title: 'Test 2' },
  { name: 'T-02', title: 'Test 3' }
]
```

And on my view I'm doing this:

```
<select data-bind="options: forms, 
                   optionsText: 'name', 
                   value: Form, optionsCaption: 'Select...'"></select>
```

My output JSON looks like this:

```
 "Forms": [
  {
   "Form": {
    "name": "T-01",
    "title": "Test 1"
   },
   "Title": "",
   "MAX": 0
  }
```

Sorry for the long explanation, I really don't how describe this. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the computed observable on title property.

```
    function Form(form, title, max) {
    var self = this;
    self.Form = ko.observable(form);
    self.Max = ko.observable(max);
    self.forms = ['T-01', 'T-02', 'T-03'];
    self.Title = ko.computed(function() {
       if(self.Form() === "T-01")
       {
         return 'Test-1'
       }
       else if(self.Form() === "T-02")
       {
         return 'Test-2'
       }
       else {
        return 'Test-3'
       }
  });    
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17wdq9p2/1/) for your example.